# How to draw excel line chart based on this multiple category?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to draw line chart that have multiple categories, months and section.

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you tried creating a chart? If yes, how does it differ from the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to provide more information about your desired line chart. It would help us understand your issue better.

If you choose whole data to create a line chart, you would get a chart like the following screenshot.
The different category of "eat", "broken" and "mature" would shown on X-axis. Then the month of "Oct", "Nov" and "Dec" would be repeated on X-axis.

[image]

If you do not like to repate the month, you may change the layout of the data, then insert a PivotChart.

[image]

If you do not change the layout of the data, the pivotchart would be the following picture.

[image]

The above are all of my simple analysis, you may provide more description of requirement according to my simple analysis.